# Tag Badge Tracker is not being reset when tag is lost

Tags: bug, tag-badges, badge-progress

Today, I saw that a user set the silver tag badge as the next tag badge. But the user didn't have the bronze badge yet.

[image]

To get bronze badge, the user needs 100 score but he has only 98.

This is what I believe has happened:

1. User had score of 100, and got the bronze css badge.
2. User chose to track the silver css badge.
3. Answer with 2 upvotes of that user got deleted, dropping the score to 98.
4. User lost the bronze CSS badge.
5. Badge tracker still show the current selection, i.e. was not reset even though it's now showing "wrong" selection.

Can this please be fixed so that tag badge tracker is reset when the relevant badge is lost?

Comment: The score is far from being live. Think it's updated once a day, at 3 AM (UTC), and many time it breaks, so it takes even longer. The user most likely earned the badge already, or is at least eligible to earn it (i.e. 100+ score), and it simply wasn't updated in the display yet. And the badge tracker probably work with the live data, not cached info.

Comment: The user lost a 2 rep today. Before that, a rep event occured in July 18. That is 1 month ago

Comment: "The user didn't win this previously" are you sure about that?

Comment: @SagarV it could also be that one of their older answers was deleted. That wouldn't show up in their reputation history.

Comment: I believe so because the link _https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/333/css?userid=_ shows _did not earn this badge_. also the rep history didn't show much downvotes on his css tagged answers

Comment: Are we sure that users aren't removed from that page if they lose the badge?

Comment: We can't sure so I checked his whole rep history. He didn't get much downvotes on css tagged answers

Comment: @Glorfindel that may be a valid reason but if that is the case, I think the next badge should be downgraded.

Comment: Deleted posts are not shown in the profile page, so most likely answer with +2 got deleted while that user had the bronze badge and the silver tracked. Ideally, this *should* trigger reset of the badge tracker, but it's not. /cc @Cai.